# Angular : Property Binding on a div tag

Tags: angular, property-binding

I have a custom JS file that shows a countdown bar on a div tag.
This is the html code :

**Component.html**

```
<div data-countdown="2021-11-05"></div>
```

In my component I have a date value for simplicity let's say it's as follow :

**Component.ts**

```
dateValue : any = '2021-08-08'
```

I want this dateValue to be bound to the html attribute value of **data-countdown**.

Although when trying this :

```
<div [data-countdown]="dateValue"></div>
```

or this

```
<div data-countdown="{{dateValue}}"></div>
```

I get a compilation error saying :

> cannot bind to 'data-countdown' since
> it is a known property of 'div'.

I want to keep the same html coding and not call the js logic in my component, is there any way I can pass a dynamic value to data-countdown of the div tag ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using attr. then your specific attribute should work with div.

```
<div [attr.data-countdown]="dateValue"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

To use attribute binding, try this:

```
<div attr.data-countdown="{{dateValue}}"></div>
```

or

```
<div [attr.data-countdown]="dateValue"></div>
```